# How to easily parse a text with custom tag format

Tags: python, parsing

I have text with open/close double bracketed tags [[tag]]/[[/tag]], and I want to apply a specific function to all text EXCEPT text inside tags.

I've already looked at the python parsers but they're very complicated, I couldn't get them to work.

To give an example, I want to transform:

"text text text [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] text text text [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] text text"

In

"TEXT TEXT TEXT [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] TEXT TEXT TEXT [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] TEXT TEXT"

Comment: Are there multiple tags? Could they be wrapped? Transforming to a standard tag regime and then using standard tools is probably the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this with a flag should help.

```
def customtag(string):
    lock = 0
    fstring = ''
    for st in string.split(' '):
        if '[' not in st and lock != 1:
            fstring += f'{st.upper()} '
        else:
            lock = 1
            fstring += f'{st} '
            if '/' in st:
                lock = 0
    print(fstring)
    return fstring


customtag("text text text [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] text text text [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] text text")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using re:

```
import re

# raw text example
raw_text = "text text text [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] text text text [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] text text"

# get text outside tags
convert_text = re.split('\[\[tag\]\].*?\[\[/tag\]\]',raw_text)
convert_text = [string.upper() for string in convert_text]

# get text inside tags with tags
remaining_parts = re.findall('\[\[tag\]\].*?\[\[/tag\]\]', raw_text)
remaining_parts.extend(' ')

# zip two lists
zipped_data = list(zip(convert_text, remaining_parts))

# convert into list
data = []
for item in zipped_data:
    data.append(item[0])
    data.append(item[1])

# join strings
out_string = ''.join(data)
```

Output:

```
TEXT TEXT TEXT [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] TEXT TEXT TEXT [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] TEXT TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a flag to check the start and end of the tags. Something like code shown below,

```
>>> s = "text text text [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] text text text [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] text text"
>>> new_string = []
>>> caps=True

>>> for el in s.split():
    if '/' in el:
        caps=True
        new_string.append(el)
        continue
    elif '[[' in el:
        caps=False
    if caps:
        new_string.append(el.upper())
    else:
        new_string.append(el)


>>> " ".join(new_string)
'TEXT TEXT TEXT [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] TEXT TEXT TEXT [[tag]] text text [[/tag]] TEXT TEXT'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using a stack.

```
from sys import stdin


def transform(text):
    return text.upper()

open_tag = '[[tag]]'
close_tag = '[[/tag]]'
tag_stack = []
output_tokens = []
for line in stdin:
    tokens = line.split(' ')
    print(tokens)
    for token in tokens:
        output_token = token
        if len(tag_stack) == 0:
            output_tokens.append(transform(output_token))
        else:
            output_tokens.append(output_token)
        if token == open_tag:
            tag_stack.append(open_tag)
        elif token == close_tag:
            tag_stack.pop()
print(' '.join(output_tokens))
```